# SfDataGrid.columns.length == DataGridRowAdapter.cells.length: is not true

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sfdatagrid

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building ScrollViewWidget(dirty, state: _ScrollViewWidgetState#f352d):
SfDataGrid.columns.length == DataGridRowAdapter.cells.length: is not true

columnSizer: _customColumnSizer,
columnWidthCalculationRange: ColumnWidthCalculationRange.allRows,
columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.auto,

Comment: This problem is solved. having both the length of your column and the length of the cells of the DataGridRow be the same length

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.